# javascript, for function, var seems to behave strangely

Tags: javascript

For the following code I get UNDEFINED, Entering Loop, UNDEFINED, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2. I understand why I only get a single 2 (I think), but I'm having trouble understanding why I get two 0?

```js
'use strict';
console.log(message);

console.log('Entering Loop');
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(message);
  var message = 'number: ' + i;
  console.log(message);
}
```

Comment: So on the first run of the loop the first console.log will bee undefined, because message has not been set. Then message = "number: 0". On the second loop, the message is still "number: 0" and so on

Comment: You really simply need to go through this step by step with pen and paper if necessary.

Comment: Are you confused about the `0` or about the `undefined`? If it’s the first: you have two `console.log`s in your loop. What did you expect? If it’s the second: it’s variable hoisting.

Comment: As a rule of thumb use ++i over i++ and you won't go wrong.

Comment: @tinker-tailer How will this change anything here?

Comment: In order to get the behavior he was expecting to.

Comment: @tinker-tailer No, that changes literally nothing in this situation

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @GilesLewey `i` will increase by 1 at the *end* of every iteration of the loop

Answer (score 2):

You are logging before and after you set the variable. `var` does not restrict the variable to the block so the old value sticks around. On your first loop iteration you are getting

```
undefined
number: 0
```

On the second you are getting

```
number: 0
number: 1
```

And on the final iteration you are getting

```
number: 1
number: 2
```

When a loop executes: The first part (`var i = 0;`) is ran before looping starts. The second part (`i < 3`) is ran before each iteration to determine whether to continue or not, and the third part (`i++`) is ran after each iteration. If the second part is truthy the loop doesn't restart. Here is your loop unrolled.

```js
'use strict';
var message;
console.log(message); // "undefined"

console.log('Entering Loop');
var i = 0;

// loop if i < 3, i === 0
console.log(message); // "undefined"
message = 'number: ' + i;
console.log(message); // "number: 0"
i++; // i === 1

// loop if i < 3, i === 1
console.log(message); // "number: 0"
message = 'number: ' + i;
console.log(message); // "number: 1"
i++; // i === 2

// loop if i < 3, i === 2
console.log(message); // "number: 1"
message = 'number: ' + i;
console.log(message); // "number: 2"
i++; // i === 3

// loop if i < 3, i === 3
```

Comment: I like this, but it might be worth mentioning in your unrolled example using a comment on the `console.log(message);` directly after the first `i++` that the message still equals `'number: 0'` because it hasn't been updated yet, even though `i` is now `1`

Comment: I tweaked it a bit to show that the variable is reused/hoisted and added log comments.What do you think @NickA

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 0):

Entering the loop your `number` is undefined.

Within the loop it's set to "Number = 0".

Entering the loop again `number` is still set to "Number = 0" and beeing overwritten with "Number = 1".

Entering the loop again `number` is still set to "Number = 1" and beeing overwritten with "Number = 2".

Entering the loop again i == 3 thus it ends.

You could have easily done this with a pen and some paper.